# variable not working with the createContext, how should i pass this trough the state

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const MovieContext = createContext();

const MovieProvider = (props) => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([
    {
      name: "Super Man and The Silly Wonder Woman",
      price: " 54£",
      id: 21,
    },
    {
      name: "League Of Sheppards",
      price: " 54£",
      id: 81,
    },
    {
      name: "Mr Marin The Billionaire",
      price: " 54£",
      id: 21,
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MovieContext.Provider>{props.children}</MovieContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export { MovieProvider };
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyledMovie } from "./movie-list.style";
import { Movie } from "../movie/movie.components";

const MovieList = () => {
  return (
    <StyledMovie>
      {movies.map((movie) => (
        <Movie name={movie.name} price={movie.price} key={movie.id} />
      ))}
    </StyledMovie>
  );
};

export { MovieList };
```

Variable not working with the createContext, how should I pass this trough the state? thank you, guys!
Line 8:8:  'movies' is not defined it works in .js but if I use jsx and import the data the useState works fine as soon as I pass it again with createContext like in Js, it dies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `value` prop to the provider

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const MovieContext = createContext();

const MovieProvider = (props) => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([
    {
      name: "Super Man and The Silly Wonder Woman",
      price: " 54£",
      id: 21,
    },
    {
      name: "League Of Sheppards",
      price: " 54£",
      id: 81,
    },
    {
      name: "Mr Marin The Billionaire",
      price: " 54£",
      id: 21,
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MovieContext.Provider value={movies}>{props.children}</MovieContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export { MovieProvider };
```

and access it using `useContext`. You need to import `MovieContext`.

```
import React,{useContext} from "react";
import { StyledMovie } from "./movie-list.style";
import { Movie } from "../movie/movie.components";

const MovieList = () => {
  const movies = useContext(MovieContext);
  return (
    <StyledMovie>
      {movies.map((movie) => (
        <Movie name={movie.name} price={movie.price} key={movie.id} />
      ))}
    </StyledMovie>
  );
};

export { MovieList };
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but, it didn't work. I will try other solutions it works fine in js but not with jsx components. Thank you very much!

Comment: did you import `MovieContext` in MovieList component

Answer (score 0):

In MovieProvider you need to pass like below
<MovieContext.Provider value={{movies}}>{props.children}</MovieContext.Provider>

And on MovieList

const { movies } = React.useContext(MovieContext);